# body-parser and multer reading multipart + json

Tags: node.js, express, multer, body-parser

In my `nodejs` `express` app I am using `body-parser` to read json requests and `multer` for file upload. I always send some info along in a json as well, because based on that, I need to know if the user is allowed to upload or not. For testing I use this `httpie` command.

```
http -vf POST localhost:9090/upload file@test.txt id=638381
```

The request passes through several middlewares, but only the middlewares after `multer` have access to `req.body.id` before `multer` I get an empty json for `req.body`.

In the minimal example below, currently only `gridfsUpload` can see the id, but if I move `multer` up or down this changes.

```
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express')
var bodyParser  = require('body-parser');
var argv = require('minimist')(process.argv.slice(2),{default:{port:8081}});
var multer  = require('multer');

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    dir = __dirname+ '/tmp/'

    cb(null, dir)
  },
})

var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true,limit:'10mb' }));
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '10mb'}));

app.use((req,res,next) => {


    console.log("body 1",req.body)
    console.log("head 1",req.header)
    next()

    })


var gridfsUpload = function(options){
    return function (req, res, next) {
    console.log("body 2",req.body)
    console.log("head 2",req.header)
        res.end()


    }
}

var checkrole_measurement = (options) => {
    return function (req, res, next) {

    console.log("body 3",req.body)
    console.log("head 3",req.header)
    next()

    }   
}

app.post('/upload',

                checkrole_measurement(),
                multer({ storage: storage }).any(),
                gridfsUpload(),
        function(req,res,next){
                            ;
                }
);    


var httpServer = http.createServer(app);
httpServer.listen(argv['port']);
```

I would really like to check on the id before `multer` because this way an otherwise unauthorized person can upload the file and later, when I can check that this should not have happened I need to delete it. It would be easier if I just didn't pass the request to `multer` in the first place.

Comment: Keep in mind that when a large file is uploaded the request body will be sent in chunks to the server, it doesn't all just show up in one go. `multer` will read in those pieces as they arrive and stream them to a file. If you have something else in your request body *after* the file then there'll be no way you can access that until after the file has been read in, in many cases the client may not even send those later pieces until the earlier ones have been consumed. You could move the `id` to the URL or a request header instead, they're received before the body.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this:

1: Instead of passing ID in body pass them into the header. So by this way, you can easily parse id using req.headers

2: Instead of using multer as middleware you can use it as normal function.
   In this method body will parsed by body-parser and files will be uploaded by multer.

```
app.post('/upload',checkrole_measurement(),
               gridfsUpload(),
               function(req,res,next){
         multer({ storage: storage }).any() ;                  
});
```